# Networking + File Sharing

Tags: share

My newly created normal users in domain can't access the sharing and security on the right click menu in explorer, but the admins can, what's the bug?

Comment: What bug? This is called security - admins have turned that off. Point. You just can not do that as admins don't want you to do it. Take it up your escalation chain.

Comment: i know that properly ! , But I'm the Admin! oh Man !

Comment: Wll, making a proper description obviously is not something you learned. Start checking your group policies.

Comment: ok TOmTom what should be changed in group policy ? in DC or Clients ? in DC , i run gpedit.msc afterwards ?or in my DC shared folders in sysvol ? where should be changed at last?

Comment: You tell me. I have no idea about how you planned group policy setup, what machiens you talk about etc. Start analysing waht group policies you have in actual use at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Go into Folder Options on the client and verify "Use Simple File Sharing" is turned off.

For Windows XP:
http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/what-is-simple-file-sharing-and-how-to-turn-it-off/

For Windows Vista/7:
Shouldn't be as much of an issue, but this may help - http://www.home-network-help.com/file-sharing-in-windows-7.html

Comment: yes tnx alot dear

Comment: you're welcome.  If this worked for you, remember to vote it as the correct answer.  Thanks